# MaxBufferPoolSize and MaxBufferSize?

Tags: azure

This is my first post to Stack Overflow so please apologies if there is any non-conformity in it.

**Question**

I have developed a Windows Azure based site (similar to eBay) and hosted it on Azure platform. I have deployed multiple instances of web role with Azure caching enabled. Till last week everything was going fine but suddenly product search page started freezing while loading the data from db. It hangs only for specific categories which returns huge amount of data.

I read somewhere that we should enable localCache and transportProperties if we are expecting large messages. Hence I modified datacache item in my web.config as below but no luck. The page still hangs for those categories!

Could somebody please tell me what is wrong in following and show me some pointers?

> ```
> <dataCacheClient name="default" channelOpenTimeout="20000" maxConnectionsToServer="4" requestTimeout="30000">
>   <localCache isEnabled="true" sync="TimeoutBased" ttlValue="300" objectCount="10000"/>
>   <clientNotification pollInterval="300" maxQueueLength="10000"/>
>   <transportProperties connectionBufferSize="64000" maxBufferPoolSize="5242880"
>                        maxBufferSize="1242880" maxOutputDelay="2" channelInitializationTimeout="60000"
>                        receiveTimeout="600000"/>
>   <hosts>
>     <host name="<<AZURE CACHE URL>>" cachePort="22233" />
>   </hosts>
>
>   <securityProperties mode="Message">
>     <messageSecurity
>       authorizationInfo="<<KEY>>">
>     </messageSecurity>
>   </securityProperties>
> </dataCacheClient>
>
> <dataCacheClient name="SslEndpoint" channelOpenTimeout="20000" maxConnectionsToServer="4" requestTimeout="30000">
>   <localCache isEnabled="true" sync="TimeoutBased" ttlValue="300" objectCount="10000"/>
>   <clientNotification pollInterval="300" maxQueueLength="10000"/>
>   <transportProperties connectionBufferSize="64000" maxBufferPoolSize="15242880"
>                        maxBufferSize="5242880" maxOutputDelay="2" channelInitializationTimeout="60000"
>                        receiveTimeout="600000"/>
>   <hosts>
>     <host name="<<AZURE CACHE URL>>" cachePort="22243" />
>   </hosts>
>
>   <securityProperties mode="Message" sslEnabled="true">
>     <messageSecurity
>       authorizationInfo="<<KEY>>">
>     </messageSecurity>
>   </securityProperties>
> </dataCacheClient>
> ```

**My dev env,**
Azure SDK 1.8 (Oct 12), SQL Server 2008 R2, ASP.Net MVC 3

**UPDATE**

Today I deployed a build with CustomerErrors off to see the if it throws any exception, and this is what I got.
[image]

Thanks in advance

ND

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to first find out which component is truly causing your intermittent slowdowns.  Is it cache or is it SQL Azure?

If it is indeed cache,  and since you're using Azure Shared Cache (previously known as Azure AppFabric Cache)

I would suggest looking at Dedicated cache as a solution instead of Shared cache. Performance of Shared Cache can sometimes be... unpredictable since it is a multi-tenant service and data travels over a network.

Comment: Thanks lgorek for replying. Issue is definitely with cache. In between I had tried by deploying a build without cache and it had worked!

Comment: Just to clarify, my app is running on two medium instances with 1GB  (dedicated) Azure cache - I am finding it very hard to believe that these configuration is not enough for a site that hardly gets any traffic (max 2 concurrent users)! We are paying a lot to MS for above configuration and this is what we are getting!